# Compiling list of open problems

Tags: hyperref, packages, lists, footnotes, endnotes

I'm writing my thesis, and along the way I am making note of relevant open problems. I would like LaTeX to keep track of these problems and then compile them in a separate section at the end of my thesis, right before the bibliography. I would ideally like these problems to have a two-way link, that is, the initial statement of the problem would have a hyperlink to the section at the end, and then each problem in the section at the end would have a hyperlink back to its initial statement.

If anyone has a reasonably elegant solution for this, I would love to hear it. I've been thinking about it for a while, and my general idea is this: use the endnote package and the command `\let\footnote=\endnote`, then write the open problems as footnotes. This works somewhat, but there are still some bugs, given below. If you have any suggestions for any of these too, I would really appreciate it.

1. I use the package `footnotebackref` to get the two-way link, but the back link disappears once I use the command `\let\footnote=\endnote` (that is, the problems will compile at the end, but won't link back to the original statements).
2. The section at the end is entitled "Notes" and I would prefer that it be something like "Open Problems."
3. The numbering of the problems in the end section is in footnote style, that is, justified left and as a superscript. I'd like it to render as a normal numbered list.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It can be done easily enough, but please don't use previously defined macros like `\footnote`.   Macros (e.g. `\csname mynote\themynote\endcsname`) can carry information from front to back.  The aux file takes two runs but can carry information back to `\begin{document}`.  Hyperref links are handled by the PDF itself.

Comment: use package `todonotes` and print `listoftodos`?

Comment: John - Thank you, yes, I agree, and am trying something else now.

Comment: Naphaneal - thanks for the suggestion. I looked at those packages, but I think the endnotes package is closer to what I'm looking for, so now I'm trying to work with that.

Comment: @user164564 If you have a satisfactory answer, it is acceptable/encouraged for you to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

This probably comes too late for your thesis, but…

Using the `enotez` package your requirements are easily met using this setup:

```
\setenotez{
  backref ,
  list-name = Open Problems
}
```

Here is a complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{
  backref ,
  list-name = Open Problems
}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\let\footnote\endnote

\begin{document}

Text\footnote{foo}

\clearpage
\printendnotes

\end{document}
```